# Solution of complex linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

In [Brubeck, Nakatsukasa, and Trefethen - Vandermonde with Arnoldi](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09988) (example 3) they solve the following linear system:
$$\operatorname{Re}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & \cdots & z_{1}^{n} \\ 1 & \cdots & z_{2}^{n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & \cdots & z_{m}^{n}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a_{0} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n}\end{array}\right)-\operatorname{Im}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}z_{1} & \cdots & z_{1}^{n} \\ z_{2} & \cdots & z_{2}^{n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ z_{m} & \cdots & z_{m}^{n}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}b_{1} \\ \vdots \\ b_{n}\end{array}\right)\approx\left(\begin{array}{c}f_{1} \\ f_{2} \\ \vdots \\ f_{m}\end{array}\right).$$

$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & \cdots & z_{1}^{n} \\ 1 & \cdots & z_{2}^{n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & \cdots & z_{m}^{n}\end{array}\right)$.

For solving it, they use the following MATLAB code:

```
c = [real(A) imag(A(:,2:n+1))]\f;
c = c(1:n+1) - 1i*[0; c(n+2:2*n+1)];
```

The first line is equivalent to creating a vector `c=[a,b]` where $\operatorname{Re}(A)a\approx f$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A(:,2:n+1))b \approx f$ and the second one means $c=a-[0,bi]$. I was wondering how it can be solved in this way, in fact I reproduced the code of the paper in Mathematica and the results are not the same. Is there any typo in this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first line is not equivalent to what you claim in the text, I believe: that's *one* linear system containing a subtraction and not two separate linear systems.

In detail, the matrix of this linear system is obtained by concatenating horizontally `M = real(A)` and `N = imag(A(:,2:n+1))`. If you split the unknown into
$$
c = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\-b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then this linear system is
$$
f = 
\begin{bmatrix}M & N\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\-b
\end{bmatrix}
=
Ma - Nb,
$$
which corresponds to your first formula. But, ultimately, you are solving *one* linear system with matrix $\begin{bmatrix} M & N\end{bmatrix}$. The instruction `[real(A) imag(A(:,2:n+1))]` stacks matrices one next to the another; it is not a "vectorized" syntax to solve two linear systems with different matrices and the same RHS.

I suspect that's the source of the issue (and, also, possibly, not solving the linear system in the least-squares sense.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have included $\approx$ to indicate the least-squares equalities. Are you saying that '[real(A) imag(A(:,2:n+1))]\f' is a substraction?. I have typed it on MATLAB and, effectively, it is the solution of two linear systems

Comment: No, that line computes the solution (in the least-squares sense) of *one* linear system. I have expanded, I hope this solves the issue. This is just basic linear algebra, in the end.